# Roles with Profie Principal like in Stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, principal

I have to implement a membership with ***`Role Profile`***.

What does that means: ***`Role Profile`***?
For example I have a ***`Manager`*** role but I want to give him a special permissions, 
for example read special documents or add a certain data.
Or I have a member with ***`Agent`*** role that he is able to ***`readonly`***.

I am using a **`membership & roles`** providers.

Can you give a suggestion how to implement this kind of ***`Role Profile or Principal over the Application`***?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) is an article about how to configure Membership Provider (and Role Provider) in MVC.

Note: You need Membership Provider in order for Role Provider to work. *Otherwise, you will have to manually create Principal object by yourself (I do not recommend it)*.

Then add `rolemanager` tag in web.config.

```
<rolemanager defaultprovider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" 
        connectionstringname="DefaultConnection" 
        applicationname="/" />
   </providers>
</rolemanager>
```

Then use `Authorize` filter to restrict access. For example. `Authorize(Roles="Manager")`

Comment: I might been misunderstood , I have implemented membership roles, I want to have an ability to give a roles a profile.

Comment: Role provider and Profile provider are two different features. If you want a feature, you can just simply add to web.config.

Comment: You are not answering my question. I want a role -> profile. Not a member profile.

Comment: There is no such thing as `role -> profile`. Please tell us what you are trying in achieve in in layman's terms. Did you try the Scott Hanselman's link that I posted?

Comment: Omg I have written it a five times, please try to read it once more. I'm familiar with membership very deeply, I know that there is no profiles for roles, that why I'm asking here how to ? There for stackoverflow exists to ask question that you don't know the answers, if we're reading my question you would understand that I have implemented a full membership already . Ty for trying.